# "String index out of range line 7." What is wrong?

Tags: python, string, for-loop, range, cs50

Task:
Reports whether the user inputted credit card number is:

VISA, MASTERCARD, AMEX or INVALID

Amex: 15 digits -- starts with 34/37

Mastercard: 16 Digits -- starts with 51/52/53/54/55

Visa: 13-16 Digits -- starts with 4

https://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm

Quick number to check with: 378282246310005 "AMEX"

```
#Luhn algorithm to check credit card's number validity
def Luhn (x, digits):
    #Sum of every other number starting from before last n
    sum1 = 0
    i = 2
    for i in range (digits):
        digit = int(x[digits-i])
        if 2 * digit < 10: sum1 = sum1 + digit *2
        else: sum1 = sum1 + 1 + (2 * digit -10)
        i+=2
    #Some of every other number starting from last n
    sum2 = 0
    i = 1
    for i in range (digits):
        digit = int(x[digits-i])
        sum2 = sum2 + digit
        i+=2
    #Some of both and condition return
    if (sum1 + sum2) % 10 == 0: return True
    else: return False

def main():
    x = input("Insert your credit card's number for analysis\n")
    # Length check
    digits = len(x)
    if digits <13 >16:
        print("Invalid Length")
        return 1
    # Luhn algorithm check
    check = Luhn(x, digits)
    if check == False:
        print("Invalid Card Number 'luhn'")
        return 1
    # Assigning letter id to first to numbers to determine card type
    creditid1 = int(x[0])
    creditid2 = int(x[1])
    # Checking digits count and first to number to determine card type
    if digits == 15 and creditid1 == 3 and (creditid2 == 4 or 7):
        print("AMEX\n")
    elif digits == 16 and creditid1 == 5 and (creditid2 == (1,6)):
        print("MASTERCARD\n")
    elif digits == 13 or 16 and creditid1 == 4:
        print("VISA\n")
    else:
        print("Not Amex...\n Not Mastercard... \n Not Visa... \n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: At first i will be zero. x[digits] is out of range

Comment: Yes, but the program never uses x[digits]. It at least starts with x[digits-1].
But why will it be out of range anyway?

Comment: range(n) produces values from 0 to n-1.

Comment: BTW, your test on the number of digits will never fail. The condition should be : if digits < 13 or digits > 16

Comment: Thanks! changed it.

Answer (score 0):

At first `i` will be zero.
So `x[digits-0]` is surely out of range.

Lets change the loop to

```
for i in range (1,digits+1):
```

Also you should convert the input to `str` type before using `len()`.

Modified code

```
#Luhn algorithm to check credit card's number validity
def Luhn (x, digits):
    #Sum of every other number starting from before last n
    sum1 = 0
    i = 2
    for i in range (1,digits+1):
        digit = int(x[digits-i])
        if 2 * digit < 10: sum1 = sum1 + digit *2
        else: sum1 = sum1 + 1 + (2 * digit -10)
        i+=2
    #Some of every other number starting from last n
    sum2 = 0
    i = 1
    for i in range (1,digits+1):
        digit = int(x[digits-i])
        sum2 = sum2 + digit
        i+=2
    #Some of both and condition return
    if (sum1 + sum2) % 10 == 0: return True
    else: return False

def main():
    x = str(input("Insert your credit card's number for analysis\n"))
    # Length check
    digits = len(x)
    if digits <13 >16:
        print("Invalid Length")
        return 1
    # Luhn algorithm check
    check = Luhn(x, digits)
    if check == False:
        print("Invalid Card Number 'luhn'")
        return 1
    # Assigning letter id to first to numbers to determine card type
    creditid1 = int(x[0])
    creditid2 = int(x[1])
    # Checking digits count and first to number to determine card type
    if digits == 15 and creditid1 == 3 and (creditid2 == 4 or 7):
        print("AMEX\n")
    elif digits == 16 and creditid1 == 5 and (creditid2 == (1,6)):
        print("MASTERCARD\n")
    elif digits == 13 or 16 and creditid1 == 4:
        print("VISA\n")
    else:
        print("Not Amex...\n Not Mastercard... \n Not Visa... \n")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: That solved the error, but still returns false. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have u noticed theirry's comment? look for some logical errors

Comment: Yes. Doesn't input always return string?

Comment: In my case I got `TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
`

Comment: Interesting, I just ran the code you gave me with the input I gave at the begging and it gave me this:
Invalid Card Number 'luhn'

Comment: I got that too. I hadn't looked at the logic.

Answer (score 0):

This is a classical **off-by-one** error

Add one to the result

```
digit = int(x[digits-i])
```

Like this

```
digit = int(x[digits-i+1])
```

Comment: Its interesting, the wrong way of doing things did work our for you and the write way of doing things did not !